# Adding to an array of characters in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to write a class procedure that adds a new character to an array of characters, but keep stumbling across "different character length in array constructor" errors (compiling with GFortran), even when the characters lengths are, as far as I can see, the same.

Here's my function:

```
subroutine addToArray(this, newElement)
  class(MyClass), intent(inout) :: this
  character(len=*), intent(in) :: newElement
  character(len=256) :: tempElement
  character(len=256), dimension(:), allocatable :: temp

  tempElement = newElement               ! Needed otherwise newElement is of the wrong size
  allocate(temp(size(this%charArray)+1)  ! Make the char array bigger by 1
  temp = [this%charArray, tempElement]
  call move_alloc(from=temp, to=this%charArray)
end subroutine
```

This results in the error `Fortran runtime error: Different CHARACTER lengths (538976288/256) in array constructor`. However, if I print `len(this%charArray)` or `len(tempElement)`, they are both 256 characters long. So where is the 538976288 coming from?

I'm typically calling this procedure using something like `myObject%addToArray('hello')`. `this%charArray` is declared in the type definition as `character(len=256), dimension(:), allocatable :: charArray`, and allocated using `allocate(this%charArray(0))`.

Comment: It may be a compiler bug.  Which gfortran version?  Note that we are guessing the declaration of the charArray component of MyClass.  Note that Fortran 2003 permits `this%charArray = [ this%charArray, tmpElement]`

Comment: There very many bugs like this in different versions if gfortran. Just search the bug database. One way to limit these bugs is to consistently use one fixed character length.

Comment: GFortran version 6.30. charArray is declared as such: `character(len=256), dimension(:), allocatable :: charArray` and it's allocated with `allocate(this%charArray(0))` (clarified in question).

Comment: Please upload a full reproduction program that can be compiled and tested ([mcve]). But as I said I assume it will be a known bug.

Answer (score 0):

It appears it is an error which I reported to GCC more than a year ago https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70231

The workaround is to compile with optimizations at least `-O1`.

If it is not the same error, an exact reproduction case is needed including the compilation flags and all relevant details.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, using `-O1` got rid of the error for me.